# Error al enviar valor a una variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Tengo este código que es de un reproductor multimedia sin embargo me arroja un error al tratar de enviar el valor del archivo seleccionado a la variable `VIDEO_PATH`.

Aquí esta el código:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QMainWindow,
                             QWidget, QPushButton, QSlider,
                             QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer, QAudio
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget

def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
    if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/uri-list'):
        e.accept()
    else:
        e.ignore()


def dropEvent(self, e):
    if e.mimeData().hasUrls:
        for url in e.mimeData().urls():
            e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
            e.accept()
            file = str(url.toLocalFile())
    else:
        e.ignore()


# Ruta del archivo.
VIDEO_PATH = file

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.bottom_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        # Control de reproducción de video de Qt.
        self.video_widget = QVideoWidget(self)
        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.media_player.setMedia(
            QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(VIDEO_PATH)))
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)

        # Botones de reproducción y pausa.
        self.play_button = QPushButton("Pausa", self)
        self.stop_button = QPushButton("Detener", self)

        # Deslizadores para el volumen y transición del video.
        self.seek_slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.volume_slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.volume_slider.setRange(0, 100)
        self.volume_slider.setValue(self.media_player.volume())
        self.seek_slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.media_player.setPosition)
        self.volume_slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.media_player.setVolume)
        self.media_player.positionChanged.connect(self.seek_slider.setValue)
        self.media_player.durationChanged.connect(
            partial(self.seek_slider.setRange, 0))

        # Acomodar controles en la pantalla.
        self.layout.addWidget(self.video_widget)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.bottom_layout)
        self.bottom_layout.addWidget(self.play_button)
        self.bottom_layout.addWidget(self.stop_button)
        self.bottom_layout.addWidget(self.volume_slider)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.seek_slider)

        # Conectar los eventos con sus correspondientes funciones.
        self.play_button.clicked.connect(self.play_clicked)
        self.stop_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_clicked)
        self.media_player.stateChanged.connect(self.state_changed)

        # Se utiliza installEventFilter() para capturar eventos
        # del mouse en el control de video.
        self.video_widget.installEventFilter(self)

        # Personalizar la ventana.
        self.setWindowTitle("Reproductor de video")
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.bottom_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        # Reproducir el video.
        self.media_player.play()

    def play_clicked(self):
        """
        Comenzar o resumir la reproducción.
        """
        if (self.media_player.state() in
            (QMediaPlayer.PausedState, QMediaPlayer.StoppedState)):
            self.media_player.play()
        else:
            self.media_player.pause()

    def stop_clicked(self):
        """
        Detener la reproducción.
        """
        self.media_player.stop()

    def state_changed(self, newstate):
        """
        Actualizar el texto de los botones de reproducción y pausa.
        """
        states = {
            QMediaPlayer.PausedState: "Resumir",
            QMediaPlayer.PlayingState: "Pausa",
            QMediaPlayer.StoppedState: "Reproducir"
        }
        self.play_button.setText(states[newstate])
        self.stop_button.setEnabled(newstate != QMediaPlayer.StoppedState)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        """
        Establecer o remover pantalla completa al obtener
        el evento MouseButtonDblClick.
        """
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
            obj.setFullScreen(not obj.isFullScreen())
        return False
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Este es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el texto completo del error a tu pregunta? Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, ya edite la publicación con una imagen donde aparece el error

Comment: El error dice `name 'file' is not defined` y te señala a la línea 28, donde efectivamente estás asignando a `VIDEO_PATH` el valor de una variable llamada `file`, que no estaba definida previamente. ¿Dónde está la duda entonces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene los siguientes problemas de importancia:

- `dragEnterEvent` y `dropEvent` son **métodos** que debes sobrescribir **en la clase** que quieres que permita el *Drag & Drop*. Los tienes fuera de la clase de cualquier widget por lo que simplemente no hacen nada.
- **Por defecto el *Drag & Drop* está desactivado**. Debes usar el método `setAcceptDrops` en el constructor de la clase en la que quieras habilitarlo.
- Usas una variable global (aunque según las convenciones es una "constante" al escribirla en mayúsculas) para la ruta del fichero que apunta a `file`. El problema es que **`file` no existe en ningún lado en el momento que defines `VIDEO_PATH`, es una variable local del "método" `dropEvent`**. Esto es lo que causa el error que muestras. Por otro lado intentas cargar el archivo al instanciar tu clase, cuando todavía no tienes una ruta disponible. Evita las variables globales a no ser que sean imprescindibles o esté justificado su uso, la ruta del archivo puede ser perfectamente un atributo de instancia de tu clase. Por otro lado, carga el archivo en el `QMediPlayer` cuando obtengas la ruta (cuando hagas *Drag & Drop* con un archivo en este caso).

Tu código en principio podría quedar así:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QMainWindow,
                             QWidget, QPushButton, QSlider,
                             QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer, QAudio
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget




class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.video_path = ''
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.bottom_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        # Control de reproducción de video de Qt.
        self.video_widget = QVideoWidget(self)
        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)

        # Botones de reproducción y pausa.
        self.play_button = QPushButton("Reproducir", self, enabled=False)
        self.stop_button = QPushButton("Detener", self, enabled=False)

        # Deslizadores para el volumen y transición del video.
        self.seek_slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, enabled=False)
        self.volume_slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.volume_slider.setRange(0, 100)
        self.volume_slider.setValue(self.media_player.volume())
        self.seek_slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.media_player.setPosition)
        self.volume_slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.media_player.setVolume)
        self.media_player.positionChanged.connect(self.seek_slider.setValue)
        self.media_player.durationChanged.connect(
            partial(self.seek_slider.setRange, 0))

        # Acomodar controles en la pantalla.
        self.layout.addWidget(self.video_widget)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.bottom_layout)
        self.bottom_layout.addWidget(self.play_button)
        self.bottom_layout.addWidget(self.stop_button)
        self.bottom_layout.addWidget(self.volume_slider)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.seek_slider)

        # Conectar los eventos con sus correspondientes funciones.
        self.play_button.clicked.connect(self.play_clicked)
        self.stop_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_clicked)
        self.media_player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.state_changed)
        self.media_player.stateChanged.connect(self.state_changed)

        # Se utiliza installEventFilter() para capturar eventos
        # del mouse en el control de video.
        self.video_widget.installEventFilter(self)

        # Personalizar la ventana.
        self.setWindowTitle("Reproductor de video")
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.bottom_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    def play_clicked(self):
        """
        Comenzar o resumir la reproducción.
        """
        if self.media_player.state() == QMediaPlayer.PausedState:
            self.media_player.play()

        elif self.media_player.state() == QMediaPlayer.StoppedState:
            self.media_player.play()

        elif self.media_player.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.media_player.pause()

    def stop_clicked(self):
        """
        Detener la reproducción.
        """
        self.media_player.stop()

    def state_changed(self, newstate):
        if newstate == QMediaPlayer.LoadedMedia:
            print("[INFO   ]: Archivo cargado correctamente")
            self.play_button.setEnabled(True)

        elif newstate == QMediaPlayer.InvalidMedia:
            print("[WARNING]: El archivo no puede ser reproducido")
            self.play_button.setEnabled(False)

        states = {
            QMediaPlayer.PausedState: "Resumir",
            QMediaPlayer.PlayingState: "Pausa",
            QMediaPlayer.StoppedState: "Reproducir",
            QMediaPlayer.InvalidMedia: "Reproducir",
            QMediaPlayer.LoadedMedia: "Reproducir"
        }

        if newstate in states:
            self.play_button.setText(states[newstate])

        playing = self.media_player.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState or \
                  self.media_player.state() == QMediaPlayer.PausedState

        self.stop_button.setEnabled(playing)
        self.seek_slider.setEnabled(playing)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        """
        Establecer o remover pantalla completa al obtener
        el evento MouseButtonDblClick.
        """
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
            obj.setFullScreen(not obj.isFullScreen())
        return False

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/uri-list'):
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore()


    def dropEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasUrls:
            url = e.mimeData().urls()[0]
            self.file_path = str(url.toLocalFile())
            self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.file_path)))
        else:
            e.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hay algunas modificaciones, por ejemplo los botones y el slider están desactivados de inicio o cuando no hay un archivo válido cargado. Para ello se usa  la señal [`QMediaPlayer.mediaStatusChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#mediaStatusChanged).

Comment: podrias alludarme con un codigo que estoy haciendo de visualizador de espectro animado. mira aqui te dejo mi codigo, basicamento lo que necesito es saber como cambiar las propiedades visuales de las barras es decir, color,borde,efecto dropshadow o blur,[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150367/ayuda-con-visualizador-grafico-de-audio-en-python]